# Derivative of functional - how is it defined?

Tags: calculus

I am reading [these notes](http://courses.physics.ucsd.edu/2009/Fall/physics130b/Calc_Var.pdf) on calculus of variations by Joel G. Broida from the University of Colorado. 
On pg. 2 the differential ($L$) of a functional ($F$) is defined as follows:

$$F[\gamma+h]-F[\gamma]=L(h)+R(h,\gamma)$$

where $\gamma(t)$ is the curve the extremizes $F$, $h(t)$ is an arbitrarily small function (loosely stated...) and $R$ is a remainder with the property that $R(h,\gamma)=\mathcal{O}(h^2)$. In order for $F$ to be differentiable $L$ must be a linear map.

**My question:** are $L$ and $R$ functionals as well? 
The reason I ask is because their argument is $h(t)$,  which is a function.

If so, what is the meaning of $R(h,\gamma)=\mathcal{O}(h^2)$ for a functinonal?
What does it mean that $h(t)\rightarrow0$ without a change in $t$?

Comment: The answer to the first question is yes.  As for the second, $R(h,\gamma)=\mathcal O(h^2)$ should intuitively mean that if you somehow move $h^2$ along a path toward the zero function then $R$ will itself move toward the zero functional.  I don't have a rigorous definition of that, though.  From what I understand, it just comes down to what your space of candidate functions is.  For instance, if your candidate functions form a Banach space, then you can forget about the fact that your arguments are functions and just define the derivative exactly like you would for any Banach space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like in multivariable calculus, one can define both a *directional derivative* and a *derivative* or *differential* of a functional.  The distinction is as follows:

The directional derivative (or *variation*) of the functional $F[x]$ ($x$ is an element of a Banach space, say $X$) is the following limit, if it is defined:

$$
\delta F[x;y] = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{F[x+\epsilon y]-F[x]}{\epsilon}
$$  For each fixed $x$, the variation is a functional of $y$ i.e. it eats a direction $y$ and returns a number $\delta F[x;y]$

As you say, in order that $F$ be truly differentiable, we require slightly more than the directional derivative to exist for each $y$: we require a linear approximation to $F$.  Since $F$ is a functional, a linear approximation to $F$ will take the form of a *linear* functional.  From Riesz representation, this is equivalent to the existence of a fixed function $F^\prime[x]\in X^\prime$, called the *functional derivative*, such that the following holds:

$$
\delta F[x;y] = \langle F^\prime[x],y\rangle
$$

The existence of a functional derivative is equivalent to $F$ being differentiable.  To summarize:

- For each $x$, the directional derivative is a functional $\delta F[x;\cdot]$
- If this functional is linear in $y$, there exists a representative vector $F^\prime[x]$ for which the directional derivative can be computed via the formula above.

This is exactly the same situation as multivariable calculus, where the directional derivative can be computed as a dot product between the gradient vector and the unit direction; the functional derivative plays the role of the gradient vector.

As for your second question, orders of convergence for functionals require the definition of a norm.  So saying a functional is $o(h^2)$ is really saying it's $o(\|h\|^2)$ where $\|\cdot\|$ is the appropriate norm (usually a Banach or Hilbert space norm).